# Squashing previous conflicts due to irrelevant "changes"

Tags: git

Sometimes when I squash a latter commit onto an early commit, I'll get unexpected conflicts.

## The Setup

I have an example repository [here](https://github.com/jrwrigh/SOtestRepo) with the following structure.

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 3aa1300 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Refactor func(x)
* 6b8940e Add func2
* 6ead589 Add import math
* dc55678 Add func
* 9dfc660 add file.py
* c5fd61b Initial commit
```

I'll be referring to them as letter commits for ease of use:

```
D 3aa1300 Refactor func(x)
C 6b8940e Add func2
B 6ead589 Add import math
A dc55678 Add func
AA 9dfc660 add file.py
AAA c5fd61b Initial commit
```

The commit names are fairly self-explanatory, but here's an abbreviated `git log -p`:

```
commit D: Refactor func(x)

 import math

-def func(x):
-    return(x)
+def func(y):
+    return(y)

 def func2(y):
     return(y)

commit C: Add func2

 def func(x):
     return(x)
+
+def func2(y):
+    return(y)

commit B: Add import math

+import math
+
 def func(x):
     return(x)

commit A: Add func

+def func(x):
+    return(x)

commit AA: add file.py
[Add the file. Only here to have commit to rebase from]
```

## The Problem

I'm cleaning up the branch, so I want to squish `D` into `A`. So I perform a `git rebase -i HEAD~4` with the following commands:

```
pick A Add func
squash D Refactor func(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
pick B Add import math
pick C Add func2
```

Doing this leaves me with a conflict in `file.py`:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
def func(x):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return(x)
=======
import math

def func(y):
    return(y)

def func2(y):
    return(y)
>>>>>>> 3aa1300... Refactor func(x)
```

## The Question

**Why doesn't the squash just "happen"? Why does the squash bring in all the other irrelevant changes into the conflict?**

I assumed that commits essentially just stored the "diff patch" it performed. So `D` would only bring over the

```
-def func(x):
-    return(x)
+def func(y):
+    return(y)
```

and nothing else.

### The Implicit Question:

Assuming I'm just not doing the correct thing, **how should I take the "fixes" of `D` and squash them onto `A`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed that commits stored essentially just stored the "diff patch" it performed.

This is not the case: each commit stores a full snapshot of all files, intact.  When cherry-picking a commit to copy it—and rebase does that, even (or especially?) with the `squash` action—these snapshots *become* diffs, through the modified three-way merge process that `git cherry-pick` uses.  So thinking of them *as* diffs *mostly* works.  It's the *mostly* part that becomes a problem here though.

You are actually doing the right thing.  Git is being triggered, as it were, by the fact that the diffs in question are from commit `C` to commit `A` and then commit `C` to commit `D`, even though commit `C` has yet to be copied.  If you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, Git will include, where the conflict occurs, the content from the merge-base commit `C`.  This will let you see that Git is treating commit `A`—or rather, the `C`-to-`A` change-set—as *removing* `func2`, and meanwhile the `C`-to-`D` change-set modifies `func1` in lines that overlap or abut (in this case, I think "abut") this removal.

Comment: Gotcha. So is there a better/cleaner way to simply take the changes from a commit and apply it later on? Reason I ask is the actual problem I'm working on has like 15 commits between `D` and `A`, which means a lot of needless conflict resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't. Git is just working with simple text manipulations: match text group T1, delete lines 4 and 5 and insert replacement lines. Repeat for T2, T3, ..., Tn (with different delete/insert instructions). If the text doesn't match up, Git can't do anything with that, so we always need a common starting point: a merge base. The merge base for copying the effect of a commit *must* be the commit's parent, since that's how you convert from snapshot to delta.